# Recursive Folder/File Copy Powershell Script - Robocopy won't stop copying once done with list

Tags: powershell, recursion, robocopy, file-copying

I'm trying to come up with a PS script that reads folder names from a txt file and recursively finds the folders/files in a source directory and then uses robocopy to copy to a destination directory, keeping the folder names, structure and timestamps. It looks like (in the log output) the script goes down the list and copies the folders and files over just great, but when it gets to the end of the list, it begins copying EVERYTHING else in the source directory.

The txt file data looks like:

```
400033
400042
400045
400047
400058
 etc..
```

The 'script' looks like:

```
foreach ($line in 
[System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\temp\filecopy\TEST_400210_400033.txt")) { 

robocopy "J:\testSRC\$line" "S:\testDEST\$line" /DCOPY:DAT /E /R:3 /W:15 /log+:C:\temp\logs\TEST_ROBOCOPY_filecopy_Log1.txt /v /tee

}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

I've tried using Powershell's `Copy-Item` in a whole different script and was able to get that script to work but it's way too slow. Trying robocopy now. It reads and copies the files it is supposed to in the order it's supposed to, but once it's copied the list it starts a whole copy of the entire directory instead of stopping at the files in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an extra line at the end of the file?

```
400033
400042
400045
400047
400058
[Blank Line]
```

i.e. it runs through all the file names then the last line will translate to:

```
$line = ""
```

Therefore:

```
robocopy "J:\testSRC\" "S:\testDEST\" /DCOPY:DAT /E /R:3 /W:15 /log+:C:\temp\logs\TEST_ROBOCOPY_filecopy_Log1.txt /v /tee
```

e.g. robocopy the root folder: `robocopy "J:\testSRC\"`

---

EDIT:

Try outputting the file to the screen to verify the input file is correct and listing the expected directories.

```
foreach ($line in 
[System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\temp\filecopy\TEST_400210_400033.txt")) { 
    Write-Host "J:\testSRC\$line"
}
```

Comment: No, there is not a blank line at the end of the file. Do I need to remove the quotes?

Comment: I would try outputting the file to screen to verify the input file is being read correctly as expected. (see edit above). Also you should look at the log file to see what command is being run on the last copy. E.g. from the code provided, this really looks like it is not a code issue (i.e. the read file is correctly copying the correct directories), and looks like an input file issue (e.g. an extra blank line, or `*` or something), that needs specific information from the log file to figure out.